# use Yes button on cfmessagebox to submit the form

Tags: coldfusion

I can get my yesno cfmessagebox to pop up, but no matter what button is clicked, the result is always to submit. I need the yes button to submit, but the no button to take no action. I have tried to mimic a lot of examples, but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<cfform name="DeleteForm" action="SubmitESPDeleteAction.cfm" method="post" style="margin:30px;" >

<cfinput name="DeleteButton" type="text" required="yes" style="color:red;" >

<cfinput name="ConfirmDelete" type="submit" onclick="javascript:ColdFusion.MessageBox.show('CONFIRMTest')" value="Delete Record" >

<cfmessagebox name="CONFIRMTest" type="confirm" message="Are you sure you would like to delete this record?" buttonType="yesno" >

<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"  >

    function CONFIRMTest(btn)
        {if (btn == 'yes')
            submit(DeleteForm)
        }


</script>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor, do nto use `cfform`, `cfinput`, `cfmessagebox` or any other ColdFusion UI elements. They will cause more trouble than they are worth. They are poorly implemented, woefully limited and way out of date.

Comment: Agreed. But to answer the question, you are misunderstanding how it works. It is basically a bunch of <div>'s that have no connection to your <form> whatever. So use a plain button (not type=submit) to show the messagebox. To invoke a javascript function, when a button is clicked, you need to assign a `callbackhandler`. The javascript function should have parameter: name of the button clicked. Inside the function use the value to take the appropriate action. Again, there is no connection to your <form> inside the function, so use the normal DOM syntax to grab the form element and submit.

Comment: (Edit) Correction. That should say *"The javascript function for a 'confirm' box should have ONE parameter: the button clicked"*.  [See docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ea2.html) Though again, if you do a search you will find a lot of alternatives to the clunky UI stuff: one example: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfmessagebox/demo/index.cfm

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the JavaScript function conditional statement.  Rather than specifying a Boolean conditional, the original code is setting the value of  btn to "yes".

**Before**

```
    if (btn = 'yes')
```

**After**

```
    if (btn == 'yes')
```

Comment: @AL86 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have tried both adding the double equal signs and changing everything to something besides ColdFusion UI. Nothing was any different from the initial posted code.

Comment: Comment out the submit(...) and temporarily replace it with alert(btn). Check what value is displayed and compare it to your conditional.

Comment: swapped submit(DeleteForm) for alert(btn). Still deleting the record with both yes and no buttons.

Comment: Did you see a popup message with the value of btn display?

Comment: I did not. It came up with the messagebox with yes and no button options. Both took the same action of deleting the record.

Comment: Temporarily replace type="submit" with type="button" and try the test again.

Comment: Changed type to button instead of submit. The messagebox came up as always, but this time both buttons close the box and neither submit.

Comment: did the alert box display?

Comment: It did not. Just the yesno messagebox displayed.

Comment: let see if confirmtest is working at all.      function CONFIRMTest(btn)
        { alert(btn);        }

Comment: The above code strips the function down to just a statement.

Comment: Same as before. YesNo box comes up. Both buttons shut the box and do not submit.

Comment: What version of CF are you running?

Comment: Looks as if the type is the only thing that really gets any change to happen, but its all or nothing. The Yes and No buttons have no seperate functionality.